# How to disable Wysiwyg from escaping special characters

Tags: html, escaping, wysiwyg

When you enter something in Wysiwyg the result will contain escaped special characters.

For example, if you type in:

```
   Höllå
```

The result will be:

```
   H&ouml;ll&aring;
```

Is there some option in Wysiwyg that disables escaping of special characters in the result?
*Using regex to unescape everything Wysiwyg escapes is not an option for me, I really need to disable Wysiyg from producing an escaped result.*

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the solution ended up being that the following should be added:

```
entity_encoding = "raw"
```

Where Wysiwyg (TinyMCE) is getting initialized.